# How to run cmake gui from the msys2 shell

Tags: cmake, msys2, pacman-package-manager

Opening the mingw64 shell (from msys2) and typing `cmake-gui` I get the following error:

```
`$ cmake-gui
 C:/DEV/msys64/mingw64/bin/cmake-gui.exe: error while loading shared libraries:`
    Qt5WinExtras.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to fix it by installing the "extra cmake modules" with the `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-extra-cmake-modules` command, without getting results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt5WinExtras.dll is part of mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5 package. You can find package details here: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5.